# typescript type declaration shows error in IDE

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I have the following type definition:

`export type AuthType = boolean | { roles: string[]; assistant?: string[] } | (() => void);`

Now I have a line of code in which I want to check the type of my `auth` variable and assign a value or execute a function:

`req.allowed = auth === true ? this.allowed : auth.roles ? auth : auth();`

The code works fine (this line is only executed if auth is not false or null) but my IDE (webstorm) shows me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't checked whether or not `auth` is an object, so typescript is trying to prevent you from accessing the `roles` property on a function (which doesn't exist). Note that this won't throw an error but might be confusing to a future reader of the code.

The way you have it set up, you probably want to use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
req.allowed = auth === true ? this.allowed : auth?.roles ? auth : auth();
```

This will make it so that `auth?.roles` evaluates to undefined if it is a function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The ? doesn't solve the problem. You can also see the function call auth() is marked. I'm not sure if this is a bug of the IDE or if I'm doing something wrong.